# How to check for empty xml files when parsing through multiple xml files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, exception

I am trying to loop through a directory to search all xml files. I got this accomplish by doing `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and by finding every .xml type. The thing is now, there are some random xml files that are empty with no information written in them. I want to check for all files that do not have any information in them.

**Code**

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("/xmlFiles", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    //Find the XML File
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

    //Check if the XDocument doc has no root element 
    if (doc == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(File + " has NO root element");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(File + " has a root element");
    }
}
```

I tried doing a if else statement comparing the file to null after parsing the xml file but I get a error when loading my file before I can compare it.

**Error:**
System.Xml.XmlException: 'Root element is missing.'

Answer (score -1):

Could always do a try catch to see if it's empty. Dup question [How to check if xml file is empty or not using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943591/how-to-check-if-xml-file-is-empty-or-not-using-c-sharp)

```
   try
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("some.xml");
}
catch (XmlException exc)
{
    //invalid file
}
```

Comment: So I got the try catch function to work but it ends my script once it finds an error. How would I modify the try catch function where it would still continue the script and give me like a Console line error when a file is empty?

Comment: I guess it comes down to what you're trying to get out of it. If you're just trying to skip the file you could do like a method that either returns the xml doc loaded if it's a proper or return null if there was an exception. @carlosE.